# How to display a dynamically built list as a submenu of Menuitems in WPF (MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, submenu

I have no clue why this does not work. My goal is to display a list of menuitems bound with commands to the "View" menuitem. The submenu displayed when "View" is clicked will be built in the viewmodel dynamically and will depend on the values of some other properties.

Why does this not work and how do I fix it?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Addendum: "Does not work" means that nothing comes up on the display when "View" is clicked".

XAML

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Nova5.UI.Views.Ink.InkView"
       ..............................

<Grid>
        .........................

    <Menu Grid.Row="3" Height="28" >
         <MenuItem Header="Document">
            <MenuItem Header="Demographics"         Command="{Binding Demographics}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Note Pad"             Command="{Binding NotePad}"  />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Save"   Command="{Binding Save}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Print"  Command="{Binding Print}" />

        <MenuItem Header="View"   ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" >
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>                           <*--THIS DOES NOT WORK!
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem  Header="{Binding DisplayName}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
       </MenuItem>               

    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

In the ViewModel,

```
    private ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem> subItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem> SubItems
    {
        get { return this.subItems; }
        set { subItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("SubItems"); }
    }
```

In the Constructor of the ViewModel,

```
 public InkViewModel(...) : base()
    {

        subItems = new ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem>();
        subItems.Add(new MyMenuItem { DisplayName = "My first Menu Item" });
        subItems.Add(new MyMenuItem { DisplayName = "Here I am" });
```

and lastly, MyMenuItem is:

```
         public class MyMenuItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MyMenuItem()
    {
        this.subItems = new ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem>();
    }

   private string displayName;
    public string DisplayName 
    {
        get
        {
            return displayName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (displayName != value)
            {
                displayName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem> subItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem> SubItems
    {
        get { return this.subItems; }
        set { subItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("SubItems"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are setting the collection to the local variable. To make the binding work, set the collection value to public member of property.

Comment: Look at the constructor of your InkViewModel. Use your public member instead of local variable.